# Un programa que muestre por pantalla todas las vocales anteriores a cada carácter de una cadena

Tags: c

necesito escribir un programa que solicite por teclado una cadena de caracteres y a continuación, para cada carácter de la cadena, que el programa muestre por pantalla todas las vocales anteriores a dicho carácter.

```
Un ejemplo:
Escribe una cadena de caracteres: Hola_mundo
las vocales anteriores al caracter H son:
las vocales anteriores al caracter o son:
las vocales anteriores al caracter l son: o
las vocales anteriores al caracter a son: o
las vocales anteriores al caracter _ son: o a
las vocales anteriores al caracter m son: o a
las vocales anteriores al caracter u son: o a
las vocales anteriores al caracter n son: o a u
las vocales anteriores al caracter d son: o a u
las vocales anteriores al caracter o son: o a u
```

Lo que llevo hecho hasta el momento es esto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 128

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

char cadena[MAX];
int i=0, j=0, cont=0;


printf("Ingrese una cadena: ");
scanf("%s", cadena);

for (j=0;j<strlen(cadena);j++){
    printf("las vocales anteriores al caracter %c son: ", cadena[j]);
    for(i=0;i<strlen(cadena);i++){
        if((cadena[i] == 'a' || cadena[i] == 'e' || cadena[i] == 'i' ||     cadena[i] == 'o' || cadena[i] == 'u')){
        printf("%c", cadena[i]); //imprimo las vocales.
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Pero esto me imprime todas las vocales que encuantra en la cadena, he intentado insertando un bucle pero no logro hacer que imprima solo las vocales anteriores a cada caracter de la cadena.
A ver si alguien me puede decir como resolver el problema, gracias.

Comment: No sabía si editarlo, lo siento, y gracias de nuevo por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analicemos y sigamos el codigo de tu programa un poco:

```
//recorremos la cadena
for (j=0;j<strlen(cadena);j++){
    //imprimimos el valor que esta en cadena para esta posicion (?)
    printf("las vocales anteriores al caracter %c son: ", cadena[j]);
    //recorremos otra vez la cadena, cual seria la idea de esto?
    for(i=0;i<strlen(cadena);i++){
        //Comparamos la posicion en i para ver si es una vocal, esto esta bien, pero lo hacemos sobre toda la cadena...
        if((cadena[i] == 'a' || cadena[i] == 'e' || cadena[i] == 'i' ||     cadena[i] == 'o' || cadena[i] == 'u')){
            printf("%c", cadena[i]); //imprimo las vocales.
        }
    }
printf("\n");
}
```

ahora.. recorrer la cadena es correcto, pero no tendrias que ir guardando las vocales a medida que las encuentres? e ir imprimiendo eso?

Fijate que si cambiamos esto:

```
for(i=0;i<strlen(cadena);i++){
```

por esto:

```
for(i=0;i<j;i++){
```

Va a recorrer solo hasta la posicion de j donde estemos, y va a mostrar las vocales hasta ahi ;)

Esto no es el metodo mas efectivo, ya que en realidad seria ideal que fueras guardando las vocales encontradas, y no recorrer la cadena dos veces.

Comment: Genial, me volví loco intentando averiguar donde estaba el fallo, muchas gracias por la ayuda.